# Query Access Update with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access DB which contains this Fields:

- ID (autonumber)
- IDArr (numeric)
- Importo (Decimal)
- Pv (numeric)
- Closed (boolean)

I want to set the `Closed` field to true if sum of Importo is = 0 grouping by `IDArr` field and I have tried with this query:

```
UPDATE ln
SET    closed = true
WHERE  Val(idarr) = EXISTS (SELECT idarr
                            FROM   ln
                            WHERE  Val(pv) > 0
                                   AND chiuso = false
                            GROUP  BY idarrivo
                            HAVING SUM(importo) = 0
                            ORDER  BY idarr)
```

Result is 0 fields. However, if I run this query separately like this:

```
SELECT idarr
FROM   ln
WHERE  Val(pv) > 0
       AND chiuso = false
GROUP  BY idarrivo
HAVING SUM(importo) = 0
ORDER  BY idarr
```

I obtain a correct result showing a set of record.
Who can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @topsail Maybe, but i thought that was better solution. If I group the query 'exists' I obtain correctly three records which contains related IDArr and the sum of field Importo that is 0 as I asked. There is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if as you say, the inner query is correct, it sounds like you want to do something like this (I can see no reason whatever that you are trying to use `exists` in your query, that is not going to work at all - remember that `exists` evaluates to `true` or `false`, but you want the `idarr` values in your subquery, not just a `true` or `false` as to whether or not they exist):

```
update LN 
set Closed = true
where 
    IdArr in (
        select idarr from LN 
        where val(PV) > 0 
        and chiuso = false 
        group by idarrivo  
        having sum(importo) = 0)
```

Comment: Also, btw, `val(PV)` should be unnecessary if PV is a numeric field - just use `PV`

Comment: Great! it does exactly what it's supposed to do! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are using the EXISTS wrong and when you use it like beow it is much fatser than the `IN` clause

```
UPDATE ln
SET    closed = true
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   ln As ln2
                            WHERE  Val(pv) > 0
                                   AND chiuso = false
                            AND ln2.idarr = ln.idarr)
```